# Coq: Problems with List In inductive

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, induction

I'm new to Coq, but with some effort I was able to prove various inductive lemmas. However I get stuck on all exercises that uses the following inductive definition:

```
Inductive In (A:Type) (y:A) : list A -> Prop :=
     | InHead : forall xs:list A, In y (cons y xs)
     | InTail : forall (x:A) (xs:list A), In y xs -> In y (cons x xs).
```

The furthest i got was with the following lemma:

```
Lemma my_In_rev : forall (A:Type) (x:A) (l:list A), In x l -> In x (rev l).
Proof.
induction l.
simpl.
trivial.
simpl.
intros.
```

The following two lemmas I cant get past the first steps, because I get stuck on the `exists` goal right after using `intros`.

```
Lemma my_In_map :  forall (A B:Type) (y:B) (f:A->B) (l:list A), In y (map f l) -> exists x : A, In x l /\ y = f x.

Lemma my_In_split : forall (A:Type) (x:A) (l : list A), In x l -> exists l1, exists l2, l = l1 ++ (x::l2).
Proof.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first lemma, I added two simple sublemmas (that you can find in the list library).
The two others are more straightforward.

```
Require Import List.

Lemma In_concat_l: forall (A: Type) (l1 l2: list A) (x:A), 
   In x l1 -> In x (l1 ++ l2).
Proof.
intros A.
induction l1 as [ | hd tl hi ]; intros l2 x hIn; simpl in *.
- contradiction.
- destruct hIn.
  + left; assumption.
  + right; now apply hi.
Qed.

Lemma In_concat_r: forall (A: Type) (l1 l2: list A) (x:A), 
   In x l2 -> In x (l1 ++ l2).
intros A.
induction l1 as [ | hd tl hi ]; intros l2 x hIn; simpl in *.
- assumption.
- right; now apply hi.
Qed.

Lemma my_In_rev : forall (A:Type) (x:A) (l:list A), In x l -> In x (rev l).
Proof.
intros A x l.
induction l as [ | hd tl hi ]; intros hIn; simpl in *.
- contradiction.
- destruct hIn.
  + apply In_concat_r.
    rewrite H.
    now constructor.
  + apply In_concat_l.
    now apply hi.
Qed.

Lemma my_In_map :  forall (A B:Type) (y:B) (f:A->B) (l:list A), In y (map f l) -> exists x : A, In x l /\ y = f x.
Proof.
intros A B y f l.
induction l as [ | hd tl hi]; intros hIn; simpl in *.
- contradiction.
- destruct hIn.
  + exists hd; split.
    left; reflexivity.
    symmetry; assumption.
  + destruct (hi H) as [x0 [ h1 h2]].
    exists x0; split.
    right; assumption.
    assumption.
Qed.

Lemma my_In_split : forall (A:Type) (x:A) (l : list A), In x l -> exists l1, exists l2, l = l1 ++ (x::l2).
Proof.
intros A x l.
induction l as [ | hd tl hi]; intros hIn; simpl in *.
- contradiction.
- destruct hIn.
  rewrite H.
  exists nil; exists tl; simpl; reflexivity.
  destruct (hi H) as [ l1 [ l2 h ]].
  exists (hd :: l1); exists l2.
  rewrite <- app_comm_cons; rewrite h.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

I won't say it's less complex than Rui's answer, but I find this solution a little bit easier to understand. But in the end, they are relatively close.

Cheers, 
V.

Comment: I am struggling to understand this kind of tactics `induction l1 as [ | hd tl hi ]; intros l2 x hIn; simpl in *.`

Im trying to prove the lemmas by myself having your solutions as a guide, and I always avoid using that kind of sequenced tactics. But I cannot reproduce the proof without resorting to it.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. Using the auxiliary lemmas you and Rui suggested I was able to prove the lemmas on my own. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just for the record, `induction foo as [ pattern ]` is just here to name the new terms the tactic induction will create. You can forget it and use auto-naming. The ";" operator allows to link several tactics. `A ; B` means "perform tactic A on the current goal, then perform B on all created subgoals that might have been generated". In my case, in was just to introduce things in the context and simplify all the expression. Hope it helps.

Comment: `induction l1 as [ | hd tl hi]` means "perform induction on l1. In the nil case (first case), do nothing. In the cons (the second case, after `|`), rename the head `hd`, the tail `tl` and the induction hypothesis `hi`".

Answer (score 1):

When the goal is existentially quantified, you have to give a concrete example of an object with the stated property, and when a hypothesis is existentially quantified, you're allowed to assume one such object exists and introduce it. See FAQs [47](http://coq.inria.fr/faq?som=6#htoc57), [53](http://coq.inria.fr/faq?som=6#htoc63), and [54](http://coq.inria.fr/faq?som=6#htoc64). By the way, an `In` predicate is already defined in `Coq.Lists.List`. Check it out [here](http://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Lists.List.html). A reference for Coq tactics is [here](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactic-index.html).

A proof of the first lemma:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.

Inductive In {A : Type} (y : A) : list A -> Prop :=
  | InHead : forall xs : list A, In y (cons y xs)
  | InTail : forall (x : A) (xs : list A), In y xs -> In y (cons x xs).

Lemma L1 : forall (t1 : Type) (l1 : list t1) (o1 o2 : t1),
  In o1 (o2 :: l1) <-> o1 = o2 \/ In o1 l1.
Proof.
intros t1 l1 o1 o2. split.
  intros H1. inversion H1 as [l2 [H3 H4] | o3 l2 H2 [H3 H4]].
    left. reflexivity.
    right. apply H2.
  intros H1. inversion H1 as [H2 | H2].
    rewrite H2. apply InHead.
    apply InTail. apply H2.
Qed.

Lemma my_In_map : forall (A B : Type) (l : list A) (y : B) (f : A -> B),
  In y (map f l) -> exists x : A, In x l /\ y = f x.
Proof.
intros A B. induction l as [| z l H1].
  intros y f H2. simpl in *. inversion H2.
  intros y f H2. simpl in *. rewrite L1 in H2. inversion H2 as [H3 | H3].
    exists z. split.
      apply InHead.
      apply H3.
    assert (H4 := H1 _ _ H3). inversion H4 as [x [H5 H6]]. exists x. split.
      rewrite L1. right. apply H5.
      apply H6.
Qed.
```

Comment: The proof is much more complex than I expected, and compared to all the other exercises I've been doing